# schema.xml doesn't update after post command

Tags: xml, apache, solr

I'm new to Solr, I've been following their tutorial on the documentation and I added documents to be indexed from the examples provided : running the command on windows:

```
Java –DC=nomCore –jar path/to/post.jar path/to/fichiers.xml
```

the documents are indexed and searchable, however I didn't modify schema.xml and after indexing the documents the fields are shown in the Solr admin interface but they are not the same as the ones in schema.xml that remained unchanged.
Is that normal ? how can I synchronize between indexed documents using the post command and schema.xml ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking for updating the indexed documents with the new schema, then no SOLR doesn't support that. below are few points

1. First  once the schema.xml is changed solr service needs a restart else the new schema.xml won't be applied to new documents which are getting into SOLR.
2. Already indexed documents before the schema.xml change , are not going to get the new schema into them.if you really need that then only  way is by re-indexing those documents.

Comment: I did restart my server but nothing changed : when I go to localhos:8983/solr/#/myCore/schema , the fields shown in the dropdown are the fields of the documents that I inserted using "post" as described above and not the fields that I have in schema.xml, my questions are : 1/ when I specified the fields I needed in schema.xml, there's no indication to the db or the collection they belong to 2/how did the documents get indexed and I was able to query them and the fields appear in the solr admin interface when I didn't mention those fields in schema.xml ?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any  default schema files which is available  with SOLR installation folder placed inside the config directory.  Please have look into that. By default managed-schema file will be available make sure in your conf directory if that managed schema is available its in sync with you user defined config. if not please remove it from the directory.